# How to identify and deal with noisy data observations?

Tags: data-cleaning, training-data, noise

For example, some people put dishonest answers on a survey, some variables are known to have measurement errors, or some images are noisy. These observations are noisy and can mask the "true" signal when we train the data. How can we identify these observations and remove them to make the training set "cleaner"?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. For example, here is a sequence of numbers, in which I inserted a fake:

```
11, 8, 14, 19, 21, 15.
```

Which is it ?

Accept that the data that you get is representative of your audience, including honest and dishonest behaviors.